# Como chamar uma classe dentro de uma função

Tags: php

Eu tenho a seguinte estrutura de pastas

```
/THEME
      /vendor
        autoload.php
        /composer
          files of composer
        /jflight
           /gacookie
              /src
              /tests
              other files
  composer.json
  composer.lock
  function.php
```

dentro de src, tem a classe:

Utmz.php

```
    <?php namespace Jflight\GACookie;

use Jflight\GACookie\ParseInterface;

class Utmz extends Cookie
{
    /**
     * Timestamp
     * @var string
     */
    public $timestamp;

    /**
     * Session count
     * @var string
     */
    public $session_count;

    /**
     * Campaign number
     * @var string
     */
    public $campaign_number;

    /**
     * Source
     * @var string
     */
    public $source;

    /**
     * Medium
     * @var string
     */
    public $medium;

    /**
     * Campaign
     * @var string
     */
    public $campaign;

    /**
     * Term
     * @var string
     */
    public $term;

    /**
     * Content
     * @var string
     */
    public $content;

    /**
     * Maps the string values in the cookie to the properties of the Utmz object
     * @var array
     */
    protected $keyMappings = array(
                        'utmcsr' => 'source',
                        'utmcmd' => 'medium',
                        'utmccn' => 'campaign',
                        'utmctr' => 'term',
                        'utmcct' => 'content'
                        );

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param DateTimeImmutable $date
     */
    public function __construct(\DateTime $date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;
    }

    /**
     * Parse cookie string and assign properties to this
     * @param  string $cookie The string from inside the cookie
     * @return static
     */
    public function parse($cookie)
    {
        $cookieBits = explode('.', $cookie, 5);
        $this->timestamp = $this->date->createFromFormat('U', $cookieBits[1]);
        $this->session_count = (integer) $cookieBits[2];
        $this->campaign_number = (integer) $cookieBits[3];
        $array = $this->paramsToArray($cookieBits);
        $this->setExtras($array);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Logic for setting the extras values from the cookie as object properties
     * @param array $array
     */
    protected function setExtras($array)
    {
        if (is_array($array))
        {
            foreach ($array as $key => $item)
            {
                if (array_key_exists($key, $this->keyMappings))
                {
                    $property = $this->keyMappings[$key];
                    $this->$property = $item;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logic for splitting the extra properties from string to array
     * @param  string $cookie
     * @return array
     */
    protected function paramsToArray($cookie)
    {
        if (isset($cookie[4]))
        {

            $pairs = explode('|', $cookie[4]);

            foreach ($pairs as $pair)
            {
                $item = explode('=', $pair);

                $return[$item[0]] = $item[1];
            }

            return $return;
        } 
    }
}
```

no arquivo `function.php` que esta na raiz adicionei:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/vendor/autoload.php';

function get_data_cookies(){

            // COMO EU CHAMO A CLASSE AQUI, QUE ESTA NO DIRETÓRIO /src/Utmz.php???


            // utmz

            $utmz->timestamp; // DateTime
            $utmz->session_count; // Integer
            $utmz->campaign_number; // Integer
            $utmz->source; // string
            $utmz->medium; // string
            $utmz->campaign; // string
            $utmz->term; // string
            $utmz->content; // string

}
```

Como eu chamo a classe dentro da função `get_data_cookies`?

**----------------- ATUALIZAÇÃO ----------**

```
require get_template_directory().'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Jflight\GACookie\GACookie;


function get_cookies(){

    $utma = GACookie::parse('utma');
    $utmz = GACookie::parse('utmz');
    var_dump( $utma );
    var_dump( $utmz ); 

                    //utma

             $args = $utma->time_of_first_visit; // DateTime
             $args = $utma->time_of_last_visit; // DateTime
             $args = $utma->time_of_current_visit; // DateTime
             $args = $utma->session_count; // Integer

            // utmz

             $args = $utmz->timestamp; // DateTime
             $args = $utmz->session_count; // Integer
             $args = $utmz->campaign_number; // Integer
             $args = $utmz->source; // string
             $args = $utmz->medium; // string
             $args = $utmz->campaign; // string
             $args = $utmz->term; // string
             $args = $utmz->content;  // string


}
```

no corpo da mensagem do formulario de contatos onde estou tentando usar esses dados inseri:

```
<?php get_cookies() ?>
```

mas isso retorna

```
bool(false)bool(false)
```

Comment: Na verdade estou aprendendo como usar eu tentei: `use Jflight\GACookie\GACookie;` deu o erro: Parse error: `syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in.. directory theme...functions.php on line 622`

Comment: estou tentando usar esse projeto no wordpress: https://github.com/jamesflight/Google-Analytics-Cookie-Parser-PHP

Comment: editei, coloquei a classe correta que deve ser chamada

Comment: Tentou colocar essa linha com o `use` no início no arquivo?

Comment: tentei assim, desapareceu o erro mas quando tento `var_dump($utmz->source);` retorna `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

A classe Utmz da biblioteca [Jflight/GACookie](https://github.com/jamesflight/Google-Analytics-Cookie-Parser-PHP) precisa ser instanciada e precisa de uma string que representa o cookie do Google Analytics para inicializar. Não sei o contexto que está utilizando essa biblioteca, mas tente isso:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/vendor/autoload.php';

use \Jflight\GACookie\Utmz;

function get_data_cookies(){
  $utmz = new Utmz(new Datetime());
  $utmz->parse("GA1.2.1640324400.1505291004.utmcct=testando|utmcsr=teste");  

  $utmz->timestamp; // DateTime
  $utmz->session_count; // Integer
  $utmz->campaign_number; // Integer
  $utmz->source; // string
  $utmz->medium; // string
  $utmz->campaign; // string
  $utmz->term; // string
  $utmz->content; // string
}
```

Contudo, leia o arquivo README.md da biblioteca que tem exemplos de uso bem claros: https://github.com/jamesflight/Google-Analytics-Cookie-Parser-PHP

Comment: muito obrigada pela ajuda, atualizei minha questão, sinceramente não entendi muito bem o que vc fez ao estanciar duas vezes ( um dentro da outra) `Utmz` e `Datetime`

Comment: Não conheço profundamente a idéia por trás dos cookies do Google Analytics, mas aqui está uma leitura que deve esclarecer: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookie-usage. Comente mais sobre o que está fazendo que posso tentar ajudar mais!

Comment: Criei um formulario de contato com campos basicos para o usuario, mas dentro do corpo da mensagem estou tentando imprimir quando ocorre o clique no submit o conteudo das variaveis `$utmz` e `$utma`, que são cookies parseados do Google Analytics, o mais importante pra mim por enquanto é saber se o visitante veio da pesquisa orgânica ou paga. Esse artigo é bem esclarecedor sobre os cookies do analytics [Fazendo debug de cookies e verificação de tags do Google Analytics](http://www.seodesaia.com.br/web-analytics/fazendo-debug-de-cookies-e-verificacao-de-tags-do-google-analytics)

Comment: Mas esses dados você não consegue nos relatórios do Google Analytics?